# java read from file. the last row overwrites the values of the previous lines in list

Tags: java

I have a file name `1.txt`

```
Coupe 1 2 
Coupe 3 4
```

and I have a code

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("1.txt"));
String tmp = "";
while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
String[] s = tmp.split("\\s");
comfortName = s[0];
tickets = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
baggage = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
// next code send to constructor of class from value of comfort name a parametrs.
Class[] e = new Class[]{Integer.TYPE,Integer.TYPE};
comfortName = "second.objects.carriages.type." + comfortName;
Class carriageClass = Class.forName(comfortName); Constructor constructor = carriageClass.getDeclaredConstructor(e);
passenger = (Passenger) constructor.newInstance((tickets),(baggage));
// the next line add to list a value from constructor
carriage.addPassenger(passenger);
```

add passenger code:

```
 public boolean addPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
        totalPassenger +=Passenger.getTickets();
        totalBaggage+=Passenger.getBaggage();
        return Carriage.getPassengerList() .add(passenger);
    }
```

So the result when I send it to list have something like that:

```
Coupe 3 4 
Coupe 3 4
```

But from debugger I see that values reading good. but always the last row 
overwrites the values ​​of the previous lines in list .
So when I send only one row it's working

Comment: int tickets = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  int baggage = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); should throw a NumberFormatException

Comment: yeah, i make a try catch , but for this question to smallest code i have deleted it

Comment: The java.lang.Class.newInstance() creates a new instance of the class represented by this Class object. The class is instantiated as if by a new expression with an empty argument list. The class is initialized if it has not already been initialized.

Comment: thanks ! now i understanding why

Comment: so the problem is solved. My mistake was in static variables tickets and baggage.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code

I believe you should get `tickets` and `baggage` from the splitted array

```
tickets = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
baggage = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
```

instead of reading next lines, below will throw exception

```
tickets = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
baggage = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: Yes, it will throw exception

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.Class.newInstance() creates a new instance of the class represented by this Class object. The class is instantiated as if by a new expression with an empty argument list. The class is initialized if it has not already been initialized.

This sample code is working fine for me.

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/1.txt"));
String tmp = "";
while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] s = tmp.split("\\s+");
    String comfortName = s[0];
    int tickets = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
    int baggage = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
    System.out.println(comfortName + tickets + baggage);

}
br.close();
```

}

on console :

```
Coupe12
Coupe34
```

Comment: it's trows ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. the example that i send working when i send to console values from this class. but when i'm send it to list the last row overwrites the values ​of the previous lines in list

Comment: did you try it without creating a new instance of the class constructor?

Comment: check the data in your file, line should be able to split into three substrings, proper spaces are given in between for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

Check your Passenger constructor that you create instance.

```
passenger = (Passenger) constructor.newInstance((tickets),(baggage));
```

The problem is at you constructor. If you constructor create new instance of Passenger object it will be ok. You constructor should be like that:

```
private Passenger(int tickets, int baggage){
   this.tickets = tickets;
   this.baggage = baggage;
}
```

Comment: My constructor looking like that ;) but when I'm send one passenger , all is good. So when I'm send more than one - the last passenger overrides the previous passenger